highcharts-more is not working with latest highcharts@12.0.2
I am trying to use spider web graph
import Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import HighchartsMore from 'highcharts/highcharts-more';
import HighchartsReact from 'highcharts-react-official';

import { spiderWeb } from 'feature/analytics/config';

export type SpiderWebProps = {
    data?: Array<Record<string, string | boolean | number | Array<any>>>;
};

const options = spiderWeb();

export const SpiderWeb: React.FC<SpiderWebProps> = ({ data }: SpiderWebProps) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        HighchartsMore(Highcharts);
    }, []);

    const dummyData = [
        {
            name: 'Category A',
            data: [80, 90, 70, 85, 60],
            pointPlacement: 'on',
        },
        {
            name: 'Category B',
            data: [70, 85, 60, 75, 95],
            pointPlacement: 'on',
        },
    ];
    const chartOptions = {
        ...options,
        chart: {
            polar: true, // Enable polar chart
            type: 'line', // Use line chart for spiderweb
        },
        yAxis: {
            visible: false,
        },
        series: dummyData,
    };
    return <HighchartsReact highcharts={Highcharts} options={chartOptions} />;
};

But this is not working even inside useEffect
I stumbled across a similar issue
https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=48448
Here the highcharts version was 10.0.0
I downgraded highcharts version then it started working but wanted a solution for latest highcharts version

TLDR: Just remove HighchartsMore(Highcharts) from the useEffect hook.
If you'd like to read more: From v12.0.0 when importing Highcharts as a node module, additional modules no longer require initialization. Previously modules would be first imported, then initialized:
// Imports for Highcharts v11
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import addAccessibility from 'highcharts/modules/accessibility';

addAccessibility(Highcharts); // <== This no longer works!

Since v12, the module will not return a factory function, so above code will cause an error. Instead, import it like this:
// Imports for Highcharts v12
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import 'highcharts/modules/accessibility';

You can read it in the HC changelog in the upgrade notes section: https://www.highcharts.com/changelog/#highcharts-v12.0.0

Thanks Dominik, the error is gone now but I am getting a line chart instead of spider web chart
Seems like chart: { type: 'line', polar: true }, is not working

Remember to import the highcharts-more like this: import 'highcharts/highcharts-more'; and here's a working react demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-mwzt7a44?file=index.js
